# Go言語でシェルを実行する方法

Tags: go

Go言語からコマンドを打ちたいのですが、どうしたらよいのですか。

rubyではバッククオートで囲むだけで実行してくれるのですが。

Answer (score 3):

http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Output

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/
目的によって、いくつかのメソッドがあります。

Answer (score 1):

ruby のバッククォートはシェルを介して実行されます。ですので、

```
`foo -flag`
```

は実際には

```
$SHELL -c 'foo -flag'
```

として実行されます。つまり引数は `$SHELL` が解析し `foo` と `-flag` に分割されます。
golang には system(3) の様に、シェルを介してコマンドを実行する命令はありません。erukiti さんが書いておられる様に

```
exec.Command("foo", "-flag")
```

という形で Cmd オブジェクトを作成して Output から標準出力を得るか、ruby のバッククォートと同様に

```
exec.Command(os.Getenv("SHELL"), "-c", "foo -flag")
```

とする事で期待の動作が得られるかと思います。
文字列を `exec.Command` に渡す配列形式に分割したいのであれば、[go-shellwords](https://github.com/mattn/go-shellwords) が使えるかと思います。

Comment: Ruby に詳しくないのですが、 `/bin/sh -c` じゃなくて `$SHELL -c` が使われるんですか？ポータブルなプログラムを書きにくい...

Comment: ruby の backquote は spawn での実装なので、shell を介します。spawn はフォールバックで /bin/sh を見ますが、その前に SHELL を見てたと記憶しています。(処理系によるでしょうが)